# Vue-router doesn't show a component when visiting the correspondent path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Router not working properly. It looks like working

App running at:

- Local:   http://localhost:8080/

But it seems router can't see the component ((

**My Router**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Web from '@/views/Web.vue'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/web',
    name: 'Web',
    component: Web
  },

  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: function () {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
    }

  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

**My Component:**

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Web'
}
</script>
```

**My Error:**

```
 App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
```

But there are nothing happens (

What it can it be ?

May be I need some dependencies in my package.json ?

```
{
  "name": "osprey",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve ",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

or something in my vue.config.json ?

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          data: `@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";`
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: please provide a meaningful title

Comment: You have to include some more details in this question. like, what is the problem? What do you expect and what happens instead ...?

Comment: My component Web not displayed "Hello" in my path: '/web',  ..there displayed my 'App' instead

Comment: <template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
     <!-- <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Web</router-link> 
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div> -->
    <Header/>
    <div class="content"> 

      <Navbar/>
      <Home/>

    </div>
    </div>
    <router-view/> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Home from '../src/views/Home.vue'
import Header from '../src/views/Header.vue'
import Navbar from '../src/views/Navbar.vue'
export default {
  
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Navbar,
    Home
  }

Comment: @JustinMoreyl did you try out my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add the mode history to your router config as follows :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
 mode:'history',
  routes
})
```

in order to access to your paths like `/web`, but in your case you have to use `#/web` since the default mode is hash